# How to find all the documents in a table which have a given string input as one of the string in list of string column couchbase repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, sql++

I wanted to know is there any way to find all the documents in a table which have a given string input as one of the string in list of string column couchbase repository

```
@Data
@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    @Field
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Field
    private List<String> cars;
}
```

I want to find all the users who have Tesla as one of the value in list of cars
I am using ReactiveCouchbaseRepository
Thank You

Comment: Which versions of Couchbase Server / Java / Spring are you using?

Comment: @MatthewGroves I am using couch base 7.0.0 ,Java 1.8 and Spring Boot 2.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the above question.

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(cars,$1) AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
Flux<Course> findAllByCars(String car);
```

The above query worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array indexing described at https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default(DISTINCT cars); 
SELECT d.* FROM default AS d WHERE ANY v IN d.cars SATISFIES v = $1 END;
```